# How to depend on a forked third party dependency in Go

Tags: go, dependencies

New to Golang...

I am tinkering with a project that has a dependency I will like to tweak.

So far so good I see that Go uses git directly for dependency management, but I am yet to come across a straight to the point guide on how to handle the case where you want to use a modified version of a dependency.

Googling seems to be a little confusing because I run across methods around dependency management which I believe is no longer recommended, but as a new comer, it is hard to tell which is which.

So would appreciate if someone can help clarify what is the recommended way to manage dependency as at 2020, and how would you go about using a modified dependency in your project.

Pointers to links that answers the following questions is also appreciated

Comment: ... info specific to forks is here: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive

Comment: The first thing to understand is that _in_ _general_ you cannot use a Github fork at all. This does work for trivial cases only, but not in general. Forget about Github forks. What you can do is "fork a project" which creates a new, project 100% unrelated to the old one. Then use that by importing it. Maybe via replace directives. Note that the idea of "please substitute this code for that package" might be a good idea in other language, for Go it is not.

Comment: @Volker I am not sure I understand you. What is the difference between Github fork and "fork a project". I was thinking I fork the project on github, then it will exist in my own namespace, with my own username in the url, then I can replace the github url in my project with the new one. Is this different from the approach you hinted at?

Comment: @Volker "Note that the idea of "please substitute this code for that package" might be a good idea in other language, for Go it is not" - also I am not sure what you mean by this. I have experience with Java mostly and I am not sure we have what you are trying to describe. It will be appreciated, If you can expatiate on your point

Comment: Just clicking "fork" on Github produce "just" a Github fork. This project might not even build and if it builds it might not work properly. You have to manually go through the code and make it work again properly, at least by adjusting all import paths and maybe import paths in code using reflection too.

Comment: If package A depends on package B and B depends on C in version x.y then A depends on C in that version transitively. It might be sensible to use x.(y+3) for A and this can be done trivially via go.mod. But what you seem to want to do is replace package C (or B?) by some different package D (your fork, which _is_ a different package). This is no longer "dependency management".

Answer (score 0):

usually i'm using  [glide](https://github.com/Masterminds/glide), here you can change dependencies for any repo or even commit that you need, and it's easy to maintain.